# In developing Class Scheduling System, it is possible to use only the Representation Method/Chromosome of Genetic Algorithm?

Tags: scheduling, genetic-algorithm

In developing Class Scheduling System, it is possible to use only the Representation Method/Chromosome of Genetic Algorithm?

This is the source article that Im using about class scheduling using GA.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23111/Making-a-Class-Schedule-Using-a-Genetic-Algorithm

Credits to the owner of article.